# Setting DataGridTemplateColumn CellTemplate programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpfdatagrid, wpf-4.0

This question is similar to others that have been posted, but none seem to offer the solution that works here.

Problem:
Trying to create a `DataGridTemplateColumn` at runtime with a particular DataTemplate. 
Just want a CheckBox in the DataTemplate.

For various reasons, I can't do it in XAML for this application, and I know that using `FrameworkElementFactory` is deprecated.

Here's what I have:

```
string dt = "<DataTemplate  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"  
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"  
xmlns:src="clr-namespace:WpfApplication40" > 
<CheckBox x:Name="dtCheckBox" Checked="CheckBox_Checked" /></DataTemplate>

 DataGridTemplateColumn tc1 = new DataGridTemplateColumn();
 DataTemplate datatemplate = (DataTemplate)System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Parse(dt);
 tc1.CellTemplate = datatemplate;
 dataGrid1.Columns.Add(tc1);
```

In the containing class:

```
 public void CheckBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){}
```

At runtime, I keep getting a message box:

`"Failed to create a 'Checked' from the text 'CheckBox_Checked'".`

Obviously it can't figure out where the `CheckBox_Checked` handler is in the class, but why?

If I take out the `Checked="CheckBox_Checked"` it works fine.

Thanks for your insights.

Comment: Isn't `Checked` expecting a `bool` value?  I was under the impression that `Checked` was denoting if the `CheckBox` defaults checked or unchecked.  Try `true` or `false`.  Of course I could be totally wrong.

Comment: `Checked` is an event looking for a class method (RoutedEventHandler)

Comment: Yep... just read the documentation.  I was thinking of `isChecked`.  My apologies.  Looking for a viable answer now =)